# Very strange error when building tensorflow on RedHat

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

Trying to build TensorFlow as instructed here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Strangely getting error:

```
ERROR: /home/eladw/.cache/bazel/_bazel_eladw/dbbd970aeeecbb3cd584d511cefda723/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:642:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf_archive//:python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so' failed (Exit 1).
     external/protobuf_archive/python/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.cc:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
```

Even though I have python-dev installed.

```
Package python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And I assume you did run ./configure? What bazel version and what tensorflow version do you build?

Comment: @mhlopko Thanks. Yes ran ./configure. Bazel 5.4.0 (downloaded linux installer). TensorFlow v1.3.0-rc2 (git clone).

Comment: This usually means that the build is looking for Python in the wrong place. I suspect you'll need to modify the TensorFlow build to look for Python in another path. Tensorflow only promises to support building on Ubuntu, and building on Redhat is community-supported. But if you figure it out, please send a Github PR!

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when I did a **yum install python36-devel** *after* I had already started a bazel build. The **./bazel-tensorflow/external/local_config_python/BUILD** had already cached an incomplete list of headers. **bazel clean** then re-running the build fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't apply to your case exactly but it will be helpful for those who come across this in the future.

I faced the same problem but on a more recent version of the stack.
The problem in my case was due to a change in Python 3.7 C API used by protobuf, downgrading to Python 3.6 solves the problem. more info [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20950) and [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/4086).